# WordPress multisite and Google Analytics in subfolders with mapped domains

Tags: google, wordpress, analytics, multiple-domains

I have a WordPress multisite with sub folders. The site's subfolders are mapped to domains, which are set to primary.

I'm using the Google Analytics Multisite Async' code to track things.

From what I can see it's tracking the sites fine (getting page hits for each site in Google Analytics) baring the original site in the multisite which in content overview lists domains then the amount of traffic it's getting along with the orginal domains traffic.

I don't want to track any other traffic for my orginal site than what goes to that. i.e. I don't want it tracking my other sites in multi-site.

e.g. `domain1.com` is my orginal and I have lots of other sites in the multisite lets say `domain2.com`, `domain3.com`.

In content overview in Analytics it's listing say `domain2.com` as content. Can I tell it to filter these out some how either in Analytics or within WordPress?

Hopefully explained that clearly!

Answer (score 2):

I think I get what you mean, but I think the setup you have might be confusing to operate and maintain in the long term.

I'd recommend scripting the insertion of the analytics tag based on the domain being accessed i.e. if domain 1 insert `UA-112454` if domain 2 insert `UA-51331` etc. This would allow you to maintain individual profiles for the different domains without screwing up custom reporting, goal tracking and so on.

You'd also get a clearer read on each site's data.

Appreciate this doesn't exactly answer the question.

Comment: cheers, yeah used a header and footer plugin in the end that lets me set a header and/or footer for sites indivdaully so just checked the code for each site in there. Seems to work thus far and probably best solution, sounds similar to your suggestion!